# Slow response time when server is idle, fast response time when server is loaded?

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, cache, response-time

I'm running a 40 thread / 125GB RAM server.

The server is based on CentOS 7.

I have noticed that the server response time is higher when the server is idle:

[image]

You can see on the screenshot here that the server response between 4pm and 10PM was lower than during other times.

I looked at the logs and GoogleBot was hitting us at 4 requests / second at that moment which loaded up the server. Most of the requests from GoogleBot were 302 redirects (large ecommerce catalog with daily changes in live products).

[image]

Here you can see the throughput of the server - during the times when the server was busy, that's when the response times were low.

How can I debug this?

What's causing this?

Could 302 redirects be cheaper than the 200 responses which skewed the data?

Could cache (Redis / Opcache / APCu) be evacuating too early which causes recreation of cache during idle time?

We're currently running:
Apache 2.4
Nginx Proxy
MySQL
Redis
Opcache
APCu
Elasticsearch

UPDATE:

Looking at the separated processes PHP is taking up the most time:

[image]

MySQL somewhat is correlating to PHP, but not fully:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Comment: @djdomi this is not really a question about capacity - its a question about why when the server is idle, the response time is higher than when the server is loaded. Could there be any specific settings I should use to reduce the response time when the server is idle? I talked to my server guy and he said it could be because 302 requests are cheaper than 200, so it can be misinterpreting data because of the cheap 302 requests.

Comment: The cause is probably something like this: In a busy state, most important parts are already cached in RAM from previous request (directories, static files, php skripts, probably even PHP bytecode, and even SQL queries), whereas in idle times every request may have to load almost everything from disk. In case your whole *server* is a VM, it may even be the case that this takes a little bit of time to obtain resources as well

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen hmmmm, but you can see from the graphs, its not like there's a huge amount of time that passes between the weird states of low vs high response time. I'd think the graphs would be a lot smoother in between the transitions. The Server is outfitted with NVME drives and is not really inhibited by those(3500MB/s). Most of the data is in RAM already and we're only using about 70GB out of 125GB.

Comment: FYI this is a baremetal system with NVME drives, 125 GB RAM, 2xCPUs / 40 threads.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
H) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.